# Pivotal Gemfire NoAvailableLocatorsException

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have a gemfire cluster  with version 8.1.0 running with two servers and a locator.Using Pulse UI Application I can see the cluster is up and running.

From my laptop I am able to ping the ip of the RHEL unix box where the cluster is running.

Also I am able to successfully connect to the cluster using gfsh command from my laptop:

**gfsh>connect --locator=locator-ip[15101]`**

But I try to connect to the cluster from a client spring application(using spring data gemfire 1.5.0.RELEASE) running in my laptop  using below spring data gemfire cache xml:

The client cache xml is as below:

```
<gfe:pool id="gemfire-pool" subscription-enabled="true" >
        <gfe:locator host="locator-ip" port="locator-port"/>
</gfe:pool>
```

But I am getting below exception:

```
com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.NoAvailableLocatorsException: Unable to connect to any locators in the list [locator-host:15101, locator-ip/locator-ip:15101]
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.AutoConnectionSourceImpl.findServer(AutoConnectionSourceImpl.java:136)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.ConnectionFactoryImpl.createClientToServerConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:206)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.pooling.ConnectionManagerImpl.borrowConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:214)
```

A simillar question has been posted

[Gemfire client server topology throws NoAvailableLocatorsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441315/gemfire-client-server-topology-throws-noavailablelocatorsexception)

But the above  error is in a different method in ConnectionManagerImpl class.

EDIT:
The cache xml has below client-cache declaration:

```
<util:properties id="gemfire-props">
        <prop key="log-level">error</prop>
</util:properties>

<gfe:client-cache id="gemfireCache" pool-name="gemfire-pool" properties-ref="gemfire-props">

<gfe:client-region id="skuInfoRegionBean" pool-name="gemfire-pool"
        name="SKU_INFO" shortcut="CACHING_PROXY">
</gfe:client-region>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a network issue.It works when I try from office but does not work from home via vpn.

Answer (score 1):

What version of *Spring Data GemFire* and *GemFire* are you running?  Also, if you could share your Spring config configuring the GemFire ClientCache (& Pool) connecting to your cluster running the RHEL server(s), that would be helpful.

My understanding is that your cluster is running on the "remote" RHEL UNIX machine(s) and your client is running from your laptop, correct?

Based on your Gfsh `connect` command syntax, your Spring config would need to look similar to...

```
<gfe:pool ...>
  <gfe:locator host="locator-ip" port="15101"/>
</gfe:pool>

<gfe:client-cache/>

...
```

The `NoAvailableLocatorsException` message seems peculiar... "*Unable to connect to any locators in the list [locator-host:15101, **locator-ip/locator-ip:15101**]*" and not quite correct.

Comment: Well, you renamed the Pool bean so did you specify the Pool on the individual client Regions... <gfe:client-region id="Example" shortcut="PROXY" pool-name="gemfire-pool"/>.  Note, it is not strictly necessary to explicitly name the ClientCache (default is "gemfireCache") or Pool beans (default is "DEFAULT") unless you have configured more than 1 Pool.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this...I edited the question to add more detail

Comment: Right, but the NoAvailableLocatorsException message is a bit misleading. I.e. the Exception message is calling out 2 individual Locators "[locator-host:15101, locator-ip/locator-ip:15101]" listening on the same port but on seemingly different "hosts" (e.g. "locator-host" and "locator-ip").  (Side-note: I am guessing you substituted aliases for actual names/IPs, here ).  However, your Spring (Pool bean) config only declares 1 Locator (<gfe:locator host="locator-ip" port="15101"/>)... the Locator running on "locator-ip" listening on 15101.

Comment: The locator-host in "[locator-host:15101, locator-ip/locator-ip:15101]" is nothing but the hostname of the same RHEL box whereas locator-ip is the ip address of the same RHEL box....There is actually only one locator running on port 15101 in that RHEL box

Comment: Somehow GemFire does not think so, hence the "[value1, value2]".  Never-the-less, if as you say, locator-host == locator-ip, then it should not matter.  However, based on your Spring config, there should be only *1* value in the array of values in the error message of the Exception.  Anyway, I don't believe there to be a problem with Spring Data GemFire in this case.  SDG's PoolFactoryBean just uses GemFire's PoolFactory to configure (with the Locator using addLocator(host, port)) and create a Pool instance.  This works reliably outside possible network issues.

Comment: 1 more suggestion... start reducing the number of variables in the equation, i.e. test your Spring configuration between your client and server by running both the the client and server locally (on your localhost).  That will tell you whether you have a configuration or network issue.  Also, forgot to mention, don't expect `gfsh>connect --locator=host[port]` to be the same as a client cache Pool connection to the same Locator.  The code paths are significantly different as are the resulting protocols that will eventually be used.